# Query in Dynamic Select Menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I have two models `Employee` , `EmployeeDepartment`. I made a dynamic select menu so when I choose a department it will filter employees depending on that department using the following code by `simple_form`

```
<%= f.input :employee_id , collection: @departments, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :employees, include_blank: false %>
```

Note: `@departments = EmployeeDepartment.order(:name)`

What I want to do is:

Before having dynamic selection I used this code in order to fetch specific employees

```
<%= f.association :employee, :collection => @supervisors_list, :label_method => :full_name, :value_method => :id, include_blank: false  %>
```

Note that: `@supervisors_list = Employee.where('guidance_supervisor' => true).order(:first_name)`

guidance_supervisors.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_id').parent().hide()
  employee = $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_id').html()
  $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_department_id').change ->
    department = $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_department_id :selected').text()
    escaped_department = department.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(employee).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_department}']").html()
    if options
      $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_id').html(options)
      $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_id').parent().show()
    else
      $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_id').empty()
      $('#guidance_supervisor_employee_id').parent().hide()
```

After adding the dynamic select I am not able to use `@supervisors_list` which makes the menu fetch all employees. I need to be able to use `@supervisors_list` again, is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: Please add dynamic selection code and full controller action code.

Comment: its a normal controller , i added what is related to my question only. , also the js code added to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon/blob/master/README.md). It has a `watch` feature that can help reload data without reloading page [see here](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-gon-watch)

Te problem with your code is only that it filters the page without reloading it. So basically being the `@supervisors_list` built server side you can:

1. use an ajax method to get the new filtered `@supervisor_list` from the server (gon watch or directly use jQuery `.ajax`)
2. add the `@supervisor_list` data to your page javascript and filter it after department filtering (also through gon or [read this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript))

Comment: what about the code i have ? its working but i need to get specific employees not all employees

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to implement the same.

https://gist.github.com/romansklenar/3077281

This may help you to fix the problem.